# How to create the function in the postgresql to return the column value and update the table and also x locking the table?

Tags: postgresql

I have a table name xyz with single column C1 having the value 100

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_complaintID () 
   RETURN TABLE (
      complaintID VARCHAR
) 
AS $$
BEGIN
   RETURN QUERY SELECT
      complaintID
   FROM
      getcomplaint

END; $$ 

LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

when i will call this function it should return the value 100 and also update the table with plus one e.g 100+1 every time when i call the function it should return the value of the table and also update the table value with one. After that it should apply the x lock on the table

Comment: If you have a column `C1` in your table `xyz`, then where does `complaintid` come from? But more importantly you can not add numbers to a varchar value. Why is something that you want to treat as a number stored in a varchar column? That will give you a lot of headaches. Don't do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it shouldn't lock the table. You want to lock the *row* so that nobody else can do the same thing until you are done.

```
UPDATE getcomplaint
SET complaintID = complaintID + 1
RETURNING complaintID - 1;
```

This will automatically lock the row and block everyone else who tries to do the same.

Comment: its give me an error ERROR:  column "complaintID" does not exist LINE 3: RETURNING complaintID - 1